# Absolute sum of coefficient of (1-x)^b (1+x)^{(n-b)} 

Tags: co.combinatorics

Let $f(x)=(1-x)^b (1+x)^{(n-b)}= \sum_{i=0}^n a_ix^i$, where $n$ is a positive
integer and $b$ is a non-negative integer less than $n$. I want to find an
upper bound on $\sum_{i=0}^n |a_i|$ other than the trivial upper bound $2^n$. 
Also for $b=0,1,\frac{n}{2}$, it is easy. Is there any integration type of approach
for this problem?

Comment: a. Typeset your question.
b. the symbol $e$ stands for a frequently used constant, and using it in this context is very confusing.

Comment: The coefficient $a_i$ is a value of a Krawtchouk polynomial. A lot is
known about their asymptotics. See for instance http://www6.cityu.edu.hk/rcms/publications/preprint21.pdf and references [11] and [15] therein.

Comment: @Stanley: Thank you very much for your kind help. I have tried to understand main results from these papers. But there is no such closed form. I need closed form as a function of $b,n$ so that I can calculate upper bound on $\sum_{i=0}^n |a_i|$. Thank you again for your help.  

Comment: You DO NOT need a closed form to get estimates. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume without loss of generality that $b\leq n/2$. Writing $f(x)=(1-x^2)^b(1+x)^{n-2b}$ shows that an upper bound is $2^{n-b}$, but this is very crude.

Comment: @Stanley: Thank you very much. For $b\leq n/3$, I have tried similar approach but do not get anything better than $2^{n-b}$. 

Answer (score 3):

This is analyzed exhaustively (also exhaustingly) by Domenici in [this 2005 preprint.](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0501042)

Comment: @Rivin: Thank you very much for the paper. In the paper author tried to estimate different $a_i$. From these estimates $\sum_{i=0}^n|a_i|$ is not easily followed for general $b$. 
Thank you again for your kind help. 